# Fetching row data as column names and set as boolean if exists or not

Tags: php, sql, pivot

I have access to a database similar to this:

users:

```
id  | name
====|========
1   | Tom
2   | Dick
3   | Harry
4   | Sally
```

exlusions:

```
user_id | exclusion
========|==============
1       | French only
3       | No magazine
4       | English only
1       | No magazine
```

Is it possible to query the database to get a result like this?

```php
$users = [
    [
        'id'           => 1,
        'name'         => 'Tom',
        'english_only' => false, // unset or null would be okay
        'french_only'  => true,
        'no_magazine'  => true,
    ],
    // . . .
];
```

I've been playing around with things like `GROUP_CONCAT`, `PIVOT`, and other examples and can't figure out how or if any of it applies.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14e374/13) -- thought I could modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13947385/2066155) to match my scenario. I didn't get all that far, and as you can see I have no idea what I am doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IF in your select to make your 3 columns out of the 1 based on their values.

```
SELECT id, name,
IF(exclusion='English only',true,false) as english_only
IF(exclusion='French only',true,false) as french_only
IF(exclusion='No magazine',true,false) as no_magazine
FROM users, exclusions
WHERE users.id=exclusions.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I started with @RightClick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30789617/2066155), but had to tweak it a bit for my SQL server.

```
SELECT User.id, User.name,
    CASE WHEN Ex.exclusion = 'English Only' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as english_only,
    CASE WHEN Ex.exclusion = 'French Only' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as french_only,
    CASE WHEN Ex.exclusion = 'No magazine' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as no_magazine
FROM users as User
LEFT JOIN exclusions Ex on User.id = Ex.user_id;
```

So much simpler than what I thought it was going to be after googling and searching SO all day...